# Appharbor SendGrid mail sending error

Tags: c#, asp.net, appharbor, sendgrid

when i send my email through appharbor using sendgrid-csharp client i got the following problem: i can send my emails to domains like gmail.com and yahoo.com but when i try to do it to my company's domain i got the following error:

554 5.7.1 Mail (id-xxxx-xxxx) appears to be unsolicited, please resend with the code udyname7 appended to email subject and ask to have your sender email whitelisted (the code udyname7 changes each 24 hours).

I tried to find any information about this error but i've foudn nothing and i have no idea what it could possibly mean.

Answer (score 2):

Some mail receivers have very aggressive anti-bulk practices. This is one of them. You'd need to do exactly what the error says to get the mail through. You need to ask your recipient to whitelist you (either by IP or address or domain) to avoid this error.